# Java 8 find max

Tags: java, java-8

I am using `max()` to find the maximum value in the list but the code below returns `4` though the max value is `90`.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4,12,19,10,90,30,60,17,90));
System.out.println(list.stream().max(Integer::max).get());
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Stream#max(Comparator)` takes a `Comparator`. You'll want to use `Integer#compare(int, int)` as that comparison function.

```
list.stream().max(Integer::compare).get()
```

You were providing `Integer#max(int, int)` as an implementation of `Comparator#compare(int, int)`. That method doesn't match the requirements of `Comparator#compare`. Instead of returning a value indicating which is biggest, it returns the value of the biggest.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `list.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke map on [intStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-)

`System.out.println(list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max().getAsInt());`

Currently your code just returns the first value from the list i.e. `4` in your case